# What is causing this simple function to plot poorly?

Tags: python, numpy, math, matplotlib, plot

This function is giving me some grief, I think something is possible rounding or not behaving like I expect it to. I've tried changing phi in small increments and the value of AFn jumps around in a way that it definitely shouldn't. It should be a round radiation pattern like this: [image: Expected radiation response]

but it's coming out spikey and discrete-looking, like this:[image: Gross wrong radiation pattern]

It has the right sort of trends, but there's clearly something wrong.
Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N = 7 #number of arrays 
phi = np.arange(0, np.pi, np.pi/100)`

def ArrayFact(phi):
    i, k, d = 0.0, 4.0, 1.0
    while i<N:
        d = d+2    
        AF = AF + np.cos( k*d * np.cos(phi) ) #array factor formula for nonuniform baselines
        i=i+1
    AFn = (1 / float(N)) * AF
    return abs(AFn)

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
plt.polar(phi, ArrayFactor(phi, N, k) * np.sin(phi))
plt.legend(loc='lower right', bbox_to_anchor = (1, 0))
plt.show()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Thanks guys, this post was a mess from start to finish but it's all worked out for the best for all of us. I think we've all learnt something here, maybe not about Python but definitely about people.

Comment: Lets start by fixing your indentation so that we may accurately assess.

Comment: And removing the erroneous back tick after `arange( ... pi/100)` so we may easily copy and paste.       
 
And calling your function `ArrayFact` by the name you defined it rather than `ArrayFactor`.   And defining `k` somewhere so we can actually use your plot call.  And the at least two additional errors that make the code as you've posted it raise errors and unusable.

Comment: I think it is spiky because you only have 100 points. np.pi/100 I think makes it 100 points. Looks better with 1000. See my answer.

Comment: Might have something to do with Gibbs phenomenon and Fourier series: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon

Comment: Ah yes sorry about the errors, I cut the code down from a much longer one later at night. When I increase the resolution, it makes more spikes, which is when I realised there was a legit problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After cleaning up the code, I was able to get this to plot rounded curves:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N = 7 #number of arrays 
phi = np.arange(0, np.pi, np.pi/500) # Increased it from np.pi/100 to get the roundedness

def ArrayFact(phi):
    i, k, d = 0, 4.0, 1
    AF = 0
    while i<N:
        d = d+2    
        AF = AF + np.cos( k*d * np.cos(phi) ) #array factor formula for nonuniform baselines
        i=i+1
    AFn = (1 / float(N)) * AF
    return abs(AFn)

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
plt.polar(phi, ArrayFact(phi) * np.sin(phi))
plt.legend(loc='lower right', bbox_to_anchor = (1, 0))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Ah thanks a bunch, I found the problem. It was actually in how I was changing d in my original code. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 7 #number of arrays 
phi = np.arange(0.0, np.pi, np.pi/1000.0)
k = 4.0


def ArrayFactor(phi,N,k):
    i = 0.0
    d = 1.0
    AF = 0.0
    while i<N:
        d = d+2    
        AF = AF + np.cos( k*d * np.cos(phi) ) #array factor formula for nonuniform baselines
        i=i+1
    AFn = (1 / float(N)) * AF
    return abs(AFn)

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
plt.polar(phi, ArrayFactor(phi, N, k) * np.sin(phi))
plt.legend(loc='lower right', bbox_to_anchor = (1, 0))
plt.show()
```